# Send AJAX request from github.io without using proxy

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, github-pages

I need to send an AJAX request from a github.io domain and get a response. My problem is that CORS is always returning that the server does not have the origin header. I am unable and will not change the server. I need some way around CORS that does not require a proxy. Since PHP cannot be hosted on GitHub.

Comment: If the destination server doesn't provide the headers or a JSONP based solution, you are basically asking for a security flaw in CORS.

Comment: @Derek How can I find out if it supports JSONP or not? I have the source of the server here. https://github.com/Cvolton/GMDprivateServer/blob/master/getGJUserInfo20.php

Comment: A JSONP service would call a callback function with the result as parameter (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Your server does not provide this.

Comment: @Derek So any way around it then? I'm able to make requests using NodeJS. I want some way to communicate with that server from my page.

Comment: No, you can't. It is a security feature. In order to make cross-origin calls from javascript in a browser, the server has to give its permission.

Comment: @DerekI'm currently doing it with a php proxy but want to find a better way. I know it's a security feature, although not a good one. I know that flash and python for instance do not error out because of CORS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Here is a list of solutions to work around these limitations, but as you can see none of these can do miracles for your use case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy